# vk api - долгое ожидание ответа

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Когда я отсылаю запрос с методом `users.get` или `groups.get`, то очень часто не могу дождаться ответа несколько минут, после чего возвращается time out.

Бывает также, что данные отдаются очень быстро. В моем проекте это очень большая проблема, и она не дает мне двигаться дальше.

Может это из-за того, что в моем приложении один пользователь (я)? Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы не было задержек и данные отдавались быстро?

Comment: Несколько раз встречал упоминание в комментариях, что вконтакте страшно глючит в последнее время.

Comment: @Илья Зеленько А вы можете выложить код запросов, которые отсылаете? Может у вас большой запрос.. или выбираете тысячу пользователей. И ответ от этих запросов желательно. может там error..  Используете что: javascript или php curl? Проблема только в данных методах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. проверьте, [жив ли ВКонтакте](https://vk.com/dev/health) – в идеале, uptime у всех должен быть 100%
2. не возвращается ли поле `error`?
3. учитываете ли вы ограничение на макс. 3 запроса в секунду, или «бомбите» как придётся? Если вы регулярно превышали частоту запросов, ВК мог внести ваш ip в кандидаты на ddos, и ограничивать скорость персонально.

Comment: Я отсылал 4 запроса в секунду. Исправил, теперь все работает отлично!